# Highcharts addPoint function show nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

In the first case i apologize for the bad english i'm french :D

So I recently tried to show some timed data on HighchartsJs.

I try to receive the data using ajax and I made a function that add all the point that i want.

But when I try to load it i see the information on the cursor but no point is shown ! :/

Here is my success function on AJAX request :

```
    success: function(resultat){

                function addPoint(){

                    var chart = $('#graphResult').highcharts();

                    for(i in resultat){

                        chart.series[0].addPoint([Date.UTC(year, month, day, resultat[i]["time"].split(":")[0]), resultat[i]["value"]], true);

                    }   

                }

                $('#graphResult').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'spline',
                            events: {
                                load: addPoint
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Température du jour'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            type: 'datetime',
                            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                                minute: '%H:%M',
                                hour: '%H:%M',
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Heure'
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Température (°C)'
                            },
                            min: 0
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                            pointFormat: '{point.y:.2f} °C'
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            spline: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name: "Température du " + String(day) + "/" + String(month) + "/" + String(year),
                        }]
                });

            }
```

As you can see, I have the information but no point is displayed : http://puu.sh/kwfnV/ad6302810a.png

Comment: I think you should check data returned from the server, i tried your code and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/69k80L58/2/

I added a console.log for the "resultat" variable, you should check data using the browser developer console. Place even a breakpoint on the for cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the help i think it's because my json is not properly parsed ! here is the output of the console.log : 0: Object
date: "2015-09-18"
id: "237"
time: "09:00:00"
type: "temperature"
value: "25"

Comment: here is an properly parsed json : [{"time":"09:00:00","value":"25"},{"time":"10:00:00","value":"30"}] but now i don't get anything in the resultat variable :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in comments, the problem is in data returned from server.

This is your Json:

```
[{"time":"09:00:00","value":"25"},{"time":"10:00:00","value":"30"}]
```

The "value" is string, then you have to parse as Float:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(
     [Date.UTC(year, month, day, 
     resultat[i]["time"].split(":")[0]), 
     parseFloat(resultat[i]["value"])], true
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69k80L58/4/

Comment: I edited the answer, i think in your scenario it's better to use parseFloat() instead of parseInt() (you can have decimal values for temperatures). Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69k80L58/4/